# Angle of Face to Camera - three.js

Tags: three.js

If I create a geometry with just one face (triangle), like this:

[CoffeeScript syntax]

```
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0))
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 10))
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
    mesh.position.x = 10
    @scene.add(mesh)
```

And I render the scene:

```
    @renderer.render(@scene, @camera)
```

How can I find out what the angle of the face is to the camera?

To clarify: If I the triangle is pointing right at the camera, so that width and hight are maximized, [similar to this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUHes.png), then I would expect an angle of 0deg (or 180deg).

If the face is at a rotation to the camera where the triangle is just on line because I am looking at it exactly sideways, [similar to this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqpNQ.png), I would expect the angle to be 90deg (or 270deg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to assume that the direction that the camera is looking is not of importance to you, only its position is.

What you want to do is take the dot product of the face normal vector (the vector that points in the direction that the triangle is facing) and the vector that points in the direction from the triangle to the camera.

[image: triangle and camera]

Here the **n1** vector is the face normal:

```
var triangleNormal = triangleMesh.geometry.faces[0].normal
```

which has unit length. **v** is the vector pointing from the triangle to the camera

```
var dirToCamera = camera.position.clone().sub(triangleMesh.position);
```

and **n2** is the just the normalized **v**:

```
dirToCamera.normalize();
```

Now, to get α, you take the dot product of **n1** and **n2**

```
var angleValue = triangleNormal.dot(dirToCamera);
```

However ´angleValue´ is not expressed in degrees, its the cosine of the degrees. This value will be 1 when triangle is facing camera, 0 when at 90 degrees and -1 when facing the opposite direction.

If you want it in degrees, just do:

```
var angle = Math.acos(angleValue) * 180/Math.PI;
```

When more thing. When calculating **n2** (`dirToCamera`), I used the triangle mesh position. If you are using a object with more than one face, you might want to calculate the center point of each triangle and use that instead of the mesh position.

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/micnil/pen/wGrLwp)